# RethinkDB notify all user stored in a row

Tags: rethinkdb

I heard of RethinkDB. So started to explore it. I am looking for a particuler solution :

Whenever a new comment is posted, a notification should be sent to all other user who had commented on that post.
A tradition solution is everytime a comment is posted, iterate through all user who commented and send them notification. But its a bit time consuming solution, cos evertime a new comment comes you have to iterate through all user.

The kind of solution I am finding (if possible through RethinkDB). I will maintain a record per post:

```
Table: PostComments
----------------------------
PostId=> user1, user2, user3.............userN
```

So if a new comment comes, i will just notify to "PostId" and as all "user" are there subscribed alreday, it should be notified automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a list of all those users with the following function, which could be set up to run when a new comment is saved.

```
r.db('DB_NAME').table('PostComments')
    .get('PostId').pluck('users').run(connection, function(error, users) {
    // notify users
    // or error
});
connection.close();
```

which will return `users === {"users":["user1","user2",...]}`

Then you could iterate over users to run your notification.